# Check subset sum for special array equation

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, subset-sum

I was trying to solve the following problem.

We are given N and A[0]

```
N <= 5000
A[0] <= 10^6 and even 
if i is odd then 
A[i] >= 3 * A[i-1]
if i is even
A[i]= 2 * A[i-1] + 3 * A[i-2]
element at odd index must be odd and at even it must be even.
```

We need to minimize the sum of the array.

and We are given a Q numbers

```
 Q <= 1000
 X<= 10^18
```

We need to determine is it possible to get subset-sum = X from our array.

What I have tried,

Creating a minimum sum array is easy. Just follow the equations and constraints.

The approach that I know for subset-sum is dynamic programming which has time complexity sum*sizeof(Array) but since sum can be as large as 10^18 that approach won't work.

Is there any equation relation that I am missing?

Comment: You might be missing how fast the sequence gets to a really big value. (I believe I saw this problem answered on SO within the last few months but I don't have a link to it.)

Answer (score 0):

We can make it with a bit of math:
sorry for latex I am not sure it is possible on stack?

let `X_n` be the sequence (same as being defined by your `A`)

I assume `X_0` is positive.

Thus sequence is strictly increasing and minimization occurs when `X_{2n+1} = 3X_{2n}`

We can compute the general term of `X_{2n}` and `X_{2n+1}`

```
v_0 = 
X0
X1

v_1 = 
X1
X2
```

the relation between `v_0` and `v_1` is

```
M_a = 
0 1
3 2
```

the relation between `v_1` and `v_2` is

```
M_b = 
0 1
0 3
```

hence the relation between `v_2` and `v_0` is

```
M = M_bM_a = 
3 2
9 6
```

we deduce

```
v_{2n} = 
X_{2n}
X_{2n+1}

v_{2n} = M^n v_0
```

Follow the classical diagonalization... and we (unless mistaken) get

```
X_{2n} = 9^n/3 X_0 + 2*9^{n-1}X_1
X_{2n+1} = 9^n X_0 + 2*9^{n-1}/3X_1
```

recall that `X_1 = 3X_0` thus

```
X_{2n} = 9^n X_0
X_{2n+1} = 3.9^n X_0
```

Now if we represent the sum we want to check in base 9 we get

```
       9^{n+1}        9^n
___   ________  ___   ___
      X^{2n+2}        X^2n
```

In the `X^{2n}` places we can only put a 1 or a 0 (that means we take the `2n-th` elem from the `A`)
we may also put a `3` in the place of the `X^{2n}` place which means we selected the `2n+1th` elem from the array

so we just have to decompose number in base `9`, and check whether all its digits or either `0,1` or `3` (and also if its leading digit is not out of bound of our array....)